# Linear regression assumptions in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

I'm trying to implement linear regression without intercept in pyspark3.0.1. So I wrote following code

```
salary_lr=LinearRegression(featuresCol='scaledFeatures',labelCol='salary'))
salary_lr.setFitIntercept(False)
trained_model=salary_lr.fit(train)
```

But I'm unable to check linear regression's assumption in pyspark. Can you suggest me how to do that?

Comment: what do you mean by "assumption"?

Comment: By assumption, I mean, 1. Linear relationship: There exists a linear relationship between the independent variable, x, and the dependent variable, y.

2. Independence: The residuals are independent. In particular, there is no correlation between consecutive residuals in time series data.

3. Homoscedasticity: The residuals have constant variance at every level of x.

4. Normality: The residuals of the model are normally distributed.